# Writing .GetValues more efficiently?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is an easier way and more efficient way to write code when trying to find multiple variables in a `Dictionary.TryGetValues` situation.

Here is my code:

```
if (present == true)
        {
            if (Verbs.ContainsKey(verb))
            {
                if (Verbs.TryGetValue(verb1st, out value))
                {
                    verb1stPresent = value;
                }
                else if (Verbs.TryGetValue(verb2nd, out value))
                {
                    verb2ndPresent = value;
                }
                else if (Verbs.TryGetValue(verb3rd, out value))
                {
                    verb3rdPresent = value;
                }
                else if (Verbs.TryGetValue(verb4th, out value))
                {
                    verb4thPresent = value;
                }
                else if (Verbs.TryGetValue(verb5th, out value))
                {
                    verb5thPresent = value;
                }
                else if (Verbs.TryGetValue(verb6th, out value))
                {
                    verb6thPresent = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    outputBox.Text = "Error between lines 229-263";
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: Sorry I didn't explain what I was trying to do.

Basically, I am making a conjugator at the moment and I want to find verbs within a dictionary that I have created a string for.

For example the string for any verb is:

```
string verb1st = verb + "1st" + tense;
```

Comment: Use a loop and an array

Comment: `"Error between lines 229-263"` lol, never change the code.

Comment: Put `verb1st` through `verb6th` into an array and iterate through that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh God.. I'm such an idiot xD

Comment: Just don't use stuff like `present == true`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny Assuming that `present` is a `bool` rather than a `bool?`. For nullable bools the `== true` can make sense.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in your program. This fragment of code makes hardly any sense without context.

Comment: @MartinSmith The OPs code leads me to an IMHO legitimate conclusion it's very improbable for `present` to be a `bool?`.

Comment: I think using an array and then  working off the array in a linq method would do the trick...

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do, but storing your strings like that is almost certainly a bad idea and is what is making your code inefficient. You should probably create a class or array to hold all of the tenses of your verb, then store the reference to that class as the value in your dictionary, with the base verb as the key.